# How to add input form to custom checkout step in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, checkout, forms, onestepcheckout

I created new checkout step in magento 2 using this link [custom checkot step](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/chec?out_new_step.html)
Now I have only a button on my new step which is declared here in **mystep.html**

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
<li id="step_code" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Step Title'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">
 
        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

Now I want to add 2 input field like dropdown button and radio button, but if I try to insert just a simple input in my **mystem.html** nothing happen!

what is the normal way to add custom inputs in the checkout custom step, and how can I save the values after I will create my input?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you do it? Can you share any resource?

Comment: i succed bu using Amasty Order Attribute. is a really nice extesnion that allow to create any of input, dropdown, radio buttons, on checkout step 1 and 2